# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','

Tags: php, json

tengo este código para filtrar por nombre una búsqueda. Esta misma, la hago mediante una variable ($valor) para que busque el nombre que escribo y luego lo almaceno en un array json.
Al hacer la dicha busqueda, tengo el error del titulo en la variable $valor

Que esta mal?

```
 <?php

    include_once "conexion.php";

    $valor = strtolower($_REQUEST['valor']);

    if (empty($valor)) {
                
                echo 'no hay nada aqui';

    }

    $query = "SELECT nombre FROM clientes1 WHERE nombre LIKE '%$valor%'";

    //EJECUTAMOS LA CONSULTA Y LA ALMACENAMOS EN $resultado

    $resultado = $conexion->query($query );

    //RECORREMOS LO QUE TRAE LA CONSULTA

     while ($registros = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
      
      $json[] = $resultado;
    }

    echo json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


    
?>
```

Comment: EN QUÉ LÍNEA TE SEÑALA EL ERROR?

Comment: @BetaM en el WHERE (nombre LIKE '%valor%)' como que las comillas simples estan mal

Comment: Intenta quitar los parentesis en el where

Comment: @NikolaTesla aun sigue el error, la consulta del query y la variable de busqueda estan correctas?

Comment: Puedes compartir el error completo ?? por que dices que aun sigue cierto ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in D:\xampp\htdocs\buscar\buscar2.php on line 9

Comment: En tu archivo **conexion.php**  tienes algo como esto ?? **$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "USUARIO", "", "DB");**

Comment: Tengo $host = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $password = '';
 $db = 'clientes';

 $conexion = @mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);

Comment: Es como dice @AlejandroGmezChuyitoSharp, tienes que poner el nombre de la función: `$query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes1 WHERE nombre LIKE '%$valor%'");`  No necesitas usar paréntesis para el `LIKE`.

Comment: El problema es que `$_REQUEST['valor']` no tiene datos. Deberías poner el código de la consulta dentro de un bloque `else`. La consulta se ejecuta aún cuando `$valor` no tiene nada, no está trayendo datos y por eso todos los otros mensajes de `null  ... null  ...` Para ver lo que hay en la superglobal pon un `var_dump($_REQUEST);` y agrega el resultado a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: Tu código quedaría mejor organizado así: `$json=array(); $valor = !empty($_REQUEST['valor']) ? strtolower($_REQUEST['valor']) : NULL; if (!$valor) { $json['error']='no hay nada aqui'; } else { include_once "conexion.php"; $query = "SELECT nombre FROM clientes1 WHERE nombre LIKE '%$valor%'"; $resultado = $conexion->query($query ); while ($registros = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {  $json[] = $resultado; } } echo json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: @A.Cedano ejecute eso mismo que escribsite y me salio: {"error":"no hay nada aqui"}

Comment: Haz una depuración de los datos, como te dije antes, pon un `var_dump($_REQUEST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Answer (score 0):

No has colocado el nombre del método que intentas llamar en la linea:

```php
$query = ($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes1 WHERE (nombre LIKE '%$valor%')");
```

Comment: Hola! tengo exactamente igual como lo has escrito. Incluso probe sacandole las comillas simples y aun sigue ese error

Answer (score 0):

El principal error es que no estas ejecutando la consulta, tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes1 WHERE nombre LIKE '%$valor%'");
```

Y lo recorres asi:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    
  //REALIZAS LO CORRESPONDIENTE
        
}
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado, pero ahora me queda asi: Notice: Undefined index: valor in D:\xampp\htdocs\buscar\buscar2.php on line 5
no hay nada aqui[{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null},{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}]

Comment: Creo que ese es $valor, no tiene indice definido como dice.

Comment: Lo que acabas de editar se lo sugerí hace rato en un comentario y dice que no funciona. Creo que @ari debería editar la pregunta, poniendo cómo tiene el código actualmente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cierto, tal vez el error sea en la variable $valor, por mas que leo el codigo no logro dar con el problema

Comment: Debe ser algo simple, pero quizá se ha liado cambiando cosas. Por eso sugiero que edite la pregunta poniendo el código actual, así se podrá revisar y ayudarlo de la mejor manera. Por lo demás, tu respuesta anterior, basada en estilo POO era bastante buena, pero @ari debe aplicarla íntegramente y si es preciso aprovechar para abandonar el confuso, horrible y verboso estilo procedural.

Comment: @A.Cedano he editado el codigo en la descripcion. Me di cuenta que estaba seleccionando con * y solo busco el nombre. De todas formas, tengo error ahora que comente arriba (null field_count)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema esta en como estas ejecutando la consulta misma, prueba de este modo

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clientes1 WHERE (nombre LIKE '%$valor%')";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas concatenando mal la variable, intentalo asi:

```
$query = "SELECT nombre FROM clientes1 WHERE nombre LIKE '%'.$valor.'%'";
```